# Do unupgraded fertilized Gnaw plants have any increased stats?

Tags: awesomenauts

There are upgrades in Awesomenauts which make fertilized Gnaw plants do more damage / have more attack speed etc.

When Gnaw spits on one of his plants, this plant gets another texture, hinting that it has other stats than just the regular unfertilized plants - even if I haven't bought any of the plant upgrades. There is no indication that these plants have improved stats though, neither in the ingame help nor on the Wiki.

*Do fertilized (i.e. spit on) Gnaw plants have any bonuses, even if I haven't bought any upgrades for them?* 
If not, is there any reason to fertilize plants (apart from the hitpoints regeneration)?

Comment: I assume that when you say fertilize, you mean when Gnaw spits on them?